# Laravel 5 validation append to rule

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I have 2 date fields. The first is required and the second is optional.

I'm having problems with the validation when the second date field is empty.

I understand why but only want to run the `before_or_equal` rule if the second date is not empty

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'start_date' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:end_date',
    'end_date' => 'nullable|bail|date|after_or_equal:start_date',
]);
```

How can I update my code ignore the rule if the date field is empty?

I did think about this

```
if($request->has('end_date')) {
    //do something
}
```

The only other option is to create a custom validation rule and compare the dates

Comment: Why aren't you using `php artisan make:request FormRequest` and having them on their own files?

Comment: I don't think so he is using FormRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to put both condition remove `|before_or_equal:end_date` from `start_date`. Only `after_or_equal:start_date` would work

Use [required_with:foo,bar,...](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-with)

Try like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'start_date' => 'required|date',
    'end_date' => 'required_with:start_date|nullable|bail|date|after_or_equal:start_date',
]);
```

Comment: I commented but your answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$rules = [
    'start_date' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:end_date',
];

if ($request->get('end_date') != '') {
    $rules['end_date'] = 'required|date|after_or_equal:start_date';
}

$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Comment: Made sense and it did the job